# How to count cumulative sum for a list in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, reduce, cumulative-sum

I have a list of groups:

`[[10, 1], [11, 1], [13, 3], [15, 10]]`

I need to calculate cumulative sum for them, to get:

`[[10, 1], [11, 2], [13, 5], [15, 15]]`.

Been trying with `Enum.reduce` but I do not know yet how to return new list as an accumulator, should I take tail of the list to get the last group and take the last amount from it or there's a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the perfect use case for `Enum.scan/2` since you want to collect the value of each reduction:

```
[[10, 1], [11, 1], [13, 3], [15, 10]]
|> Enum.scan(fn [a, b], [_c, d] ->
  [a, b + d]
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
[[10, 1], [11, 2], [13, 5], [15, 15]]
```

Comment: I didn't know Enum.scan, awesome!

Comment: Same here :) Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't get your point, so I prepared two answers based on exactly what you need.

**1. List of lists, second value is cumulative sum**

Solution without `Enum.scan` proposed by Dogbert, which is awesome one.

```
 def map_cumulative_sum(list) do
  list
  |> do_map_cumulative_sum([], 0)
 end

defp do_map_cumulative_sum([], acc, _sum_y) do
  Enum.reverse(acc)
end

defp do_map_cumulative_sum([[x, y] | t], acc, sum_y) do
  sum_y = y + sum_y
  do_map_cumulative_sum(t, [ [ x, sum_y] | acc], sum_y)
end
```

**2. Single list with result**

In this case `Enum.reduce` will do the job.

You can use version with or without accumulator (accumulator in this case would be first element of your list):

```
list = [[10, 1], [11, 1], [13, 3], [15, 10]]

# reduce list of lists to one list, where 2nd value is cumulative sum
Enum.reduce(list, fn([x, y], [acc_x, acc_y]) -> [x, y + acc_y] end)
> [15, 15]
```

Version with explicit accumulator will just have [0, 0] as second argument for `Enum.reduce`:

```
Enum.reduce(list, [0, 0], fn([x, y], [acc_x, acc_y]) -> [x, y + acc_y] end)
```